# getting an invalid item error in Webmatrix.Database query

Tags: vb.net, razor, webmatrix

I am using Webmatrix with VB.NET. I have a database declared as

```
Dim db As Database
db = Database.Open("xxx")
```

I build this query:

```
Dim strQuery As String
strQuery = "SELECT NomexSheeter.BlockNumber, NomexSheeter.WorkOrder, dbo_tbl_WIPMASTER_NF.ITEM_NBR " _
            & "FROM NomexSheeter INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_WIPMASTER_NF ON NomexSheeter.WorkOrder = dbo_tbl_WIPMASTER_NF.WORK_ORDER " _
            & "WHERE NomexSheeter.WorkOrder = @0 AND NomexSheeter.BlockNumber = @1"
```

I call the query like this:

```
Dim data = db.Query(strQuery, "99A", "901C")
```

Here is some markup...

```
<input type="hidden" id="barcodeValue" value="@data.ITEM_NBR"/>
```

I get an compilation error when running the page that says:
     'ITEM_NBR' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)'.

Since there is very little VB.NET Webmatrix documentation online, I am left guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is a collection. It is an IEnumerable(Of Object). To access properties of individual elements in the collection, you either have to use `ElementAt()` to access a specific  item or a `For Each` loop to access each element in turn.

```
Dim data = db.QuerySingle(strQuery, "99A", "901C")
<input type="hidden" id="barcodeValue" value="@data.ElementAt(0).ITEM_NBR"/>
```

Or you could use the First method to get to the first row if you are certain at least one will be returned:

```
Dim data = db.QuerySingle(strQuery, "99A", "901C")
<input type="hidden" id="barcodeValue" value="@data.First().ITEM_NBR"/>
```

If you only expect one row of data to match your criteria, you should use the `QuerySingle` method instead of the `Query` method. That returns an object, and you can access its properties directly.

```
Dim data = db.QuerySingle(strQuery, "99A", "901C")
<input type="hidden" id="barcodeValue" value="@data.ITEM_NBR"/>
```

There is more about hte various Database methods and their return types in this C#-focused article of mine, but you should be able to understand why each return type needs to be treated differently: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/214/How-To-Check-If-A-Query-Returns-Data-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: Thanks Mike! That makes perfect sense! I will try it.